# Putting points within an institution on a map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, cakephp, maps

I have a map drawn in coreldraw for points and locations within a large institution and I want to put it on google maps so that users within the institution can be able to search and locate points from where they are. Any idea on how I can go about this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps has an [upload a floor plan](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685896) page, though it's up to Google whether they accept your map addition. You might also be interested to check out [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), which is [gathering the data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Indoor_Mapping) but hasn't got it publicly visible yet.